# Cant install nvidia-docker2 on bionic Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, nvidia, docker

I'm new to `Docker` and have a limited experience working with `Linux`. 
Trying to ramp up `GIT` project (a machine learning project hosted on Github). The project uses GPU (Nvidia) and relies on `Docker` and `nvidia-docker2` and is coded in `Python (3.5)`.

Following the [README.md](https://gist.github.com/sgregnt/cae3a5081561bca7a5cbd0058c8076f4) I successfully proceed until I get an error when installing `nvidia-docker2`. (The first part of the readme.me up to and including the installation of `nvidia-docker2` is in the link above).

To elaborate a bit, the README.md file has a step by step intallation guide on how to run the project it starts with the installation of nvidia drivers and other libraries which I'm able to install and verify they are working. But when it comes to installation of `nvidia-docker2`:

```
 sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2
```

I get the following error:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-docker2 : Depends: docker-ce (= 18.03.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu) but 
                    18.05.0~ce~3-0~ubuntu is to be installed or
                   docker-ee (= 18.03.1~ee~3-0~ubuntu) but it is not
```

Any help comments are welcome! Please see some additional elaborations below, and at the end of the post, I describe some of my attempts to solve this issue.

Thanks!

---

---

**Some elaborations:**

I reach the part where I have to install docker and it goes well, (quoting from the [README.md](https://gist.github.com/sgregnt/cae3a5081561bca7a5cbd0058c8076f4)) I run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
sudo docker run hello-world
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
```

It works fine and I can verify:

```
 sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2
```

So when I check

```
sudo docker version
```

I get the lates docker for bionic ubuntu that I have.

```
Client:
 Version:      18.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.37
 Go version:   go1.9.5
 Git commit:   f150324
 Built:        Wed May  9 22:16:13 2018
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.05.0-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.5
  Git commit:   f150324
  Built:        Wed May  9 22:14:23 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

I can then check that docker is set up and can run:

```
 sudo docker run hello-world
```

so I get:

```
 Hello from Docker! 
 [...]
```

**However, when I proceed to the next block of instructions on README.md, where I have to  install `nvidia-docker2` I get an error:**

I run

```
 docker volume ls -q -f driver=nvidia-docker | xargs -r -I{} -n1 docker ps -q -a -f volume={} | xargs -r docker rm -f
 sudo apt-get purge -y nvidia-docker
 curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
 distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID)
 curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia- 
 docker.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list
 sudo apt-get update
```

and finally:

```
 sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2
```

the error appears:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-docker2 : Depends: docker-ce (= 18.03.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu) but     18.05.0~ce~3-0~ubuntu is to be installed or
                       docker-ee (= 18.03.1~ee~3-0~ubuntu) but it is not     installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

**What I tried to do to solve the issue:**

- I've googled my issue and found this [ticket](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/643) on nvidia-github. The ticket is closed but (probably due to lacking expirience with linux) I can get what they are really saying there -- Is `nvidia-docker2` is not yet supported on Ubuntu18.04 at all?
- On the same [ticket](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/643) , the last post by **rockper** suggests to install `docker.io` instead of `docker-ce`, which should solve `nvidia-docekr2` issue. I follow his suggestion, i.e. install `docker.io`  (an I also edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` as rockper recommened). Then I can verify that I've successfully installed `docker.io`, i.e:

.

```
 sudo docker version


 Client:
 Version:    17.12.1-ce
 API version:    1.35
 Go version:    go1.10.1
  Git commit:    7390fc6
  Built:    Wed Apr 18 01:23:11 2018
  OS/Arch:    linux/amd64

 Server:
  Engine:
  Version:    17.12.1-ce
  API version:    1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:    go1.10.1
  Git commit:    7390fc6
  Built:    Wed Feb 28 17:46:05 2018
  OS/Arch:    linux/amd64
  Experimental:    false
```

Which is the latest  [`docker.io` package on ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/docker.io). But I still get an error (though a bit different report)

```
 sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-docker2 : Depends: docker-ce (= 18.03.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu) but it is not 
 going to be installed or
                       docker-ee (= 18.03.1~ee~3-0~ubuntu) but it is not installable
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by installing the specific docker-ce (community edition) package and not the latest 
(which is version 18.05)

```
sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce=18.03.13-0~ubuntu
```

Complete instructions for installing docker-ce can be found at https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/